# Creating .avi video from .jpg images in opencv

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread("C:/Users/Abhilash/Desktop/myFrames/frame1.jpg",1);


     if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << endl ;
        return -1;
    }
```

gets size of the frame

```
   Size s = image.size();
   double dWidth = s.height;
   double dHeight = s.width;

    cout << "Frame Size = " << dWidth << "x" << dHeight << endl;

    Size frameSize(static_cast<int>(dWidth), static_cast<int>(dHeight));
```

Initializing videowriter

```
        VideoWriter oVideoWriter ("D:/MyVideo.avi", CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1'), 25,        
        frameSize, true);  


    if ( !oVideoWriter.isOpened() ) //if not initialize the VideoWriter     successfully, exit the program
   {
        cout << "ERROR: Failed to write the video" << endl;
        return -1;
   }



    namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

        int i;
        char buffer[50];
```

Reading the images and adding them to video file

```
      for(i=1;i<=250;i++) //putting 250 frames to MyVideo
      {

         Mat frame;

         sprintf(buffer,"C:/Users/Abhilash/Desktop/myFrames/frame%d.jpg",i);

         frame = imread(buffer,1);

          if(! frame.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << endl ;
        return -1;
    }

          oVideoWriter << (frame); //writer the frame into the file

          imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window




 if (waitKey(10) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
       {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break; 
       }
    }

    return 0;

   }
```

This code reads 250 .jpg frames and displays them properly. The size of the video file created is 5.54KB. But I am not able to play the video file(in KMPlayer).

Comment: "The size of the video file created is 5.54KB." - that's only the container/header. your box lacks the codec you required, so no frames were written at all.

Comment: @berak, Thank u. Could you suggest the necessary correction in the code. As I am new to opencv, am not able to figure it out.

Comment: install some [codecs](http://fourcc.org/) and try those. in your code you just would change the `CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1')` to something else, ie 'V' 'I' 'D' 'C'